# Why does this CreateFile() call cause a BSOD on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, winapi, crash, createfile, bsod

If I try to run this:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    CreateFile(
        TEXT("X:\\$MFT\\Folder"),
        FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

the system deadlocks (and on Windows 8, subsequently BSODs) on any further attempt to access `X:`.
(**Update:** `X:` was just a placeholder; you can replace it with any valid drive.)

It took me a while to track it down, and now I have -- but I'm baffled: what is the cause?

Comment: Is X a mapped network drive? Your description certainly sounds like a bug in the driver. What's the error code you get from BSOD? Have you sent the crash report in?

Comment: @dlev: No, `X:` was a placeholder, you can replace it with `C:` if you want to -- it crashes a lot more quickly if it's `C:`, actually. I didn't write `C:` because I was worried that someone would copy-paste it and then run it verbatim and accidentally crash his computer.

Comment: Ok, so is the name of the file important, or is it simply the combination of other flags that causes the deadlock/BSOD?

Comment: @dlev: The `\$MFT` part is important -- it seems like the system doesn't expect the Master File Table to be opened this way. What exactly causes it to crash, though, is what's baffling me -- it should just fail instead. The `\Folder` part could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an NTFS bug.

Since it is now finally [publicly known](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/05/in-a-throwback-to-the-90s-ntfs-bug-lets-anyone-hang-or-crash-windows-7-8-1/), I'm undeleting this question and posting this as an answer.